# no images stored in firebase but my app still shows them

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm learning how to use firebase, I made my first app that store and retrieve images, to do it I store the images and the urls, no problem, working fine. Today I was testing and found that if I go into firebase storage and delete everything, than my app still can retrieve the image just from the link, if I open the same link on a browser page I get this error:

```
"error": 
"code": 404,
"message": "Not Found."
```

How is it possible? I'm confused right now, I missed something about firebase, can you explain me?

This is how I create the element on firebase:

```
StorageReference dbStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance(URL_storage).getReference("images/" + element_name_add.getText());
dbStorageRef.putFile(image_to_up).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

        dbStorageRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                System.out.println("Element created and uploaded with success");
                dataSnapshot.getRef().child(element_name_add.getText().toString()).child("type").setValue(item_type);
                dataSnapshot.getRef().child(element_name_add.getText().toString()).child("time").setValue(item_time);
                dataSnapshot.getRef().child(element_name_add.getText().toString()).child("description").setValue(element_desc_add.getText().toString());
                dataSnapshot.getRef().child(element_name_add.getText().toString()).child("image_url").setValue(uri.toString());
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                System.out.println("ERROR: element not created");
            }
        });
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR");
    }
});
```

Edit: I tried to invalidate android studio cache and now the images are not displaying, so it was android studio cache I suppose, can't get why

Comment: Are you using some caching for the images?

Comment: yeah it was Glide cache issue

Comment: So most likely, the images come from the Glide cache, right?